# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function

Tags: java, dll, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to utilize a .dll written in visual basic.  I didn't write it so don't have the source code to it.  I can load it ok and display the methods inside, but get "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function" when trying to call one.  Here is my code:

```
package dlltest;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collection;

public class DllTest {
    public interface TC2005 extends Library {
        public boolean TCEnabled();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TC2005 tc2005 = (TC2005)Native.loadLibrary("TC2000Dev",TC2005.class);
        Method[] methods = tc2005.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method:methods) System.out.println(method);
        System.out.println("TCEnabled="+tc2005.TCEnabled());
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
public final boolean com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TCEnabled()

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TCEnabled': The specified procedure could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:345)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:325)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:203)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.TCEnabled(Unknown Source)
    at dlltest.DllTest.main(DllTest.java:70)
```

There are many more functions and output but just showing one for clarity.

Been reading posts on the subject all day with no joy.  Some talk about compilers mangling the method names and hence need for a FunctionMapper code.  To get the real method names everyone says to use Dependency Walker.  Tried using that to load the .dll  Lots of errors.  Also tried loading a .exe that uses the .dll and then running the Profiler option in DW.  That locks up the program. (Not Responding).

Suggestions?

Comment: VBA is not the visual basic that you are looking for.  please update your tag

Comment: you should have TC2000Dev.dll or libTC2000Dev.so in your java.library.path, system path or class path your system pointed out.

Comment: It is.  That's why the library is able to load.

Comment: Having exactly the same issue.

Comment: No response from support@worden.com.  They define this function in their interface like this:  Public Property Get TCEnabled() As Boolean.  I'm going to check into com4j.  See if I can have any better luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Cross check your version. You need function which is not present in loaded .dll . Such cases can be seen with incorrect version.